# How many lua_State can I have in a c++ program

Tags: c++, lua

As I know, when we need call lua function, we must create a lua interpreter by call **lua_State *L = lua_open()**. How many lua interpreter can open at the same time in a c++ program? If there are thousands of lua interpreters, would that effect the performance.

Comment: Lua VM works in a single OS thread (and only when you are asking VM to do some job).  To make 1000 Lua VMs work simultaneously, you should run 1000 OS threads in parallel, this will seriously impact the performance.  On the other hand, you can run all Lua VMs alternately (in round-robin fashion) from single OS thread.  `lua_open()` does not create separate OS thread.

Answer (score 0):

lua_States have memory, which uses resource.  Also only one can run at a time.  Which limits the number of simultaneous states which can be run.  But when they are "waiting" - they only use the memory for the variables and loaded modules.

Comment: But I can use lua_open() create lots of lua_State. And the address of lua_State are different